# Makecmds.sty and fontspec Error

Tags: xetex, packages

```
\usepackge{fontspec}

\usepackge[Script=Devanagari]{Kokila.ttf}
\begin{document}
   यह देवनागरी लिपि है.
\end{document}
```

This gives error of fontspec requires XeTex Or LauTex. However I have already installed fontspec package. One more problem what I getting in multilinguage font using Pollyglossia. Here it asking for makecmds.sty missing. This is also installed.

Comment: Please extend you sniplet to a full minimal example that others can copy and test as is.

Comment: the error doesn't say that fontspec is missing, it says that you should use xelatex or lualatex for the compilation.

Comment: I compiled using both Xelatex and Laulatex but still getting same error message. However, I checked all other package is ok.